# How write/replace HTML from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have an application where (non-IT) users create and maintain product pages (the products are music CDs), so the pages contain usual blurb about the CD and a track-listing.
We want to insert an mp3 music player into each track, but need to keep the in-line 'code' that that usrs add-in as simple as possible   e.g `<player url:fileRef />`

Each instance on the page would then be injected with the ~20 lines of html and the unique fileRef at display time.

What's the best way to do this?   Javascript?  jquery?
I read that `'document.write'` - isnt the answer.
Is `document.getElementByClassName("player").innerHTML = "html goes here";`  the best way>

I read that  `.getELementByClassName("player")` replaces ALL instances of the class - so how best inject the unique fileRef into each instance.

Your guidance would be most welcome

PS We already have the (html5) mp3 music player, but the html for each instance is ~20 lines.

Comment: Why don't you just create an upload field for each song title? Then they'll be able to upload mp3's, which you can then load into a player. Seems the most easy way.

Comment: You need unique IDs for each element you want to handle individually.

Comment: if vanilla js is used make sure u not fall in some crossbrowser issue - http://caniuse.com

Comment: Instead of `getReferenceByClassName`, I think you may want to use `document.getElementById`, that would select a unique DOM element... is this what you need?

Comment: Tks for fast reponses.
Glubos - we don't need them 'uploaded' they are already on-file.  I need to inject a 'player'
Cameron & SebasSBM - I dont know how many instances on a page there will be (I suppose I could agree a max).  But in anycase each instances will be the same code, exept for the url.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine if you want to add the class 'player' to each of your elements, but your selector should not be `document.getElementsByClassName("player")` as that will not differentiate any of the elements from one another. Ideally, you'd have a list of IDs that you could loop over and use to select your individual elements. Something like this could work:

```
var ids = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"];
var i;
for(i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  var player = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
  player.innerHTML = getHtmlForPlayer(id[i]); // you'll need to build this
}
```

Note, I have written this without knowing too much about how your HTML is generated, but it should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery you can use something like

```
$("player").each(function(){
  var id = $(this);
  var url = $(this).prop("url");
  $.get(url, function(data){
    $(id).html(data);
  }
}
```

Note that this is untested, i would go for span/div with a class="player", and the use of data-url tags.

```
<span class="player" data-url="url"></span>
```

then change the $("player") to $(".player")